# Laravel calling a MSSQL stored procedure which is return multiple recordsets

Tags: php, laravel

I'm call a MSsql database with parameters, this then returns 3 or so recordsets. For example.

```
AS
BEGIN
    select 'record set one' as res
    select 'record set two' as res
    select 'record set three' as res
END
```

My controller which is calling the Stored proc is as follows:

```
$data = DB::statement("EXEC usp_StoredProcedure ?,?,?", [$a,$b,$tb]);
```

How can I iterate through all the recordsets?

Comment: Ok, fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$conn = DB::connection('DBconnection');
$sql = "exec usp_getresults @param1=".$paramone.", @param2=".$paramtwo;
$pdo = $conn->getPdo()->prepare($sql);
$pdo->execute();
        // Setup output results
$rows = array();
$res = array();
        // Iterate through the recordsets
do {
      $rows = $pdo->fetchAll();
      array_push($res,$rows);
 } while ($pdo->nextRowset());
        // Output
return  $res;
```